# Rails unable to reset development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration

I tried to drop and reset my database in development with: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and it didn't work for some reason.  Now when I try to run that command I get:

```
FATAL:  database "myapp_development" does not exist
FATAL:  database "myapp_test" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist at character 315
STATEMENT:              SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

If I try only `rake db:create db:migrate` then I get the error

```
myapp_development already exists
myapp_test already exists
ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist at character 315...
```

If I run only `rake db:migrate` then I get only the last part of the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
                                    ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I tried restarting my database: `pg_ctl stop -D /usr/local/var/postgres` `pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres`, but to no avail.

I'm at a complete standstill on this one.  Anyone know how to get the database reset and re-migrated?

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34391/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17929808-rails-unable-to-reset-development-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much hassle in postgres, it turns out this had nothing to do with the database schema or postgres.

I just had to comment out my routes.rb file, which was referencing the Post model.  With routes.rb commented out, I ran the migrations just fine, and then uncommented routes.rb.

Comment: I would give you 1000 up votes if I could.  My internet connection got disrupted during db:pull resulting in some odd postgres errors on subsequent attempts to drop and start over.  This was it!